# Which ETL is best for Hbase

Tags: database, hbase, etl, loading, talend

I am using Talend open tool for extracting data from HBase. Is there any other best(Precisely : Extract more records) open source tool for extracting data from HBase and loading into another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look for an Open source tool, Talend is the best one. I could see your question 
**Precisely : Extract more records**, are you facing any issues while extracting through talend?

Secondly you can use Python to extract data, but it requires additional libraries to be installed and also need more coding efforts.

I would suggest to use Talend, and in case if you face issues on extracting more records, we can optimize and provide a better solution

Comment: My pleasure... !